# high-energy electrons vs. high-energetic electrons

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I am writing some text about a population of electrons with very high energies. Which of the following statement is correct (or "better" as compared to the others):

1. [...] a population of high-energy electrons.
2. [...] a population of high-energetic electrons.
3. [...] a population of highly-energetic electrons.

Comment: btw, I don't think `energy` is countable in this context. Maybe you want to revise your question accordingly :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`high-energy` works as a [compound modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier) (adjective). Hyphens are used to construct the compound modifiers.

`high-energetic` is incorrect.

`highly energetic` works without hyphen.

Comment: thanks for commenting on all three possibilities!

Answer (score -1):

Using "high-energy" is alright but it would be better if you specify the amount of energy and avoid using subjective terms like "high" in a scientific paper.